# What is the alias in the AndroidKeyStore to retrieve the root attestation certificate?

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-security

I want to be able to retrieve and check the general Android device attestation data (attestationIdSerial, attestationIdImei, etc...).

Google says you can retrieve the attestation data in a certificate extension (ASN.1 format).  This seems easy enough to retrieve and parse against a key generated in the Android KeyStore that we know the alias of using KeyStore.getCertificateChain(alias), but what is the alias of the root attestation certificate so that I can just get the attestation data generally without having to generate some random key / alias and then check it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot get a handle to the root attestation certificates directly.

They are not part of KeyStore or KeyChain, there's no alias. They are internal to the Keymaster and not exposed other than on the certificate chain of regular keys.

Here's a link to the file where they are defined in the reference Keymaster implementation, you can track usages from there:

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:system/keymaster/contexts/soft_attestation_cert.cpp;l=299;drc=a6a4f57064aa5f988d80b58a63ee0fc880c29ac6